# Symfony / Doctrine : problem with an entity ManyToOne to OneToOne

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many, entity, symfony4

I'm having troubles with my **Users** entity.

In my website, users can fill their collection to keep track of their Magic the gathering cards.
Every users have one and only one collection. So, I created a table "**Collection**", mapped in *OneToOne* between **Users** and **Collection**.

This table collection is mapped to a another table named "**CollectionContent**" in *ManyToOne*.
This table contains only one field, quantity. I created this table because the *ManyToMany* association doesn't allow additionnals fields.

The table collectionContent is then mapped to **Cards** in *ManyToOne*. (to simulate the *ManyToMany* with an additional field.)

**Here comes the problem** : I made a mistake while creating the entity at first and created it as ManyToOne between users and Collection. (instead of OneToOne)

And now, I'm trying to call

```
$userCollectionId = $this->getUser()->getCollection();
```

Which should return the user collection id, and I get an error message :

```
Return value of App\Entity\Users::getCollection() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, instance of App\Entity\Collections returned
```

I guess there are two possibilities :

- I cant name my entity 'Collection' ? is it a reserved word or something ?
- The methods to get the collection from the user arent good anymore because I changed the ManyToOne into OneToOne and I have to delete something, but I dont know exactly what.

Here's my Users Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsersRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email"},
 *     message="L'adresse mail est déjà utilisée."
 * )
 */
class Users implements UserInterface
{

    private const DEFAULT_IMAGE = "default.jpg";
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Length(min="5", minMessage="Votre pseudo doit faire plus de 4 caractères")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(min="6", minMessage="Votre mot de passe doit faire plus de 5 caractères")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Collections", mappedBy="users", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $collection;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Wishlists", mappedBy="users")
     */
    private $wishlists;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default" : "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $registeredAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comments", mappedBy="auteur", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comments", mappedBy="postedOnUser")
     */
    private $commentsOnUser;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, options={"default" : "default.jpg"})
     */
    private $image;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->collection = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->wishlists = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->commentsOnUser = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $role = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $role[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($role);
    }

    public function setRole(array $role): self
    {
        $this->roles = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|collections[]
     */
    public function getCollection(): Collection
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }

    public function addCollection(collections $collection): self
    {
        if (!$this->collection->contains($collection)) {
            $this->collection[] = $collection;
            $collection->setUsers($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCollection(collections $collection): self
    {
        if ($this->collection->contains($collection)) {
            $this->collection->removeElement($collection);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($collection->getUsers() === $this) {
                $collection->setUsers(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|wishlists[]
     */
    public function getWishlists(): Collection
    {
        return $this->wishlists;
    }

    public function addWishlist(wishlists $wishlist): self
    {
        if (!$this->wishlists->contains($wishlist)) {
            $this->wishlists[] = $wishlist;
            $wishlist->setUsers($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeWishlist(wishlists $wishlist): self
    {
        if ($this->wishlists->contains($wishlist)) {
            $this->wishlists->removeElement($wishlist);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($wishlist->getUsers() === $this) {
                $wishlist->setUsers(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRegisteredAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->registeredAt;
    }

    public function setRegisteredAt(\DateTimeInterface $registeredAt): self
    {
        $this->registeredAt = $registeredAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Comments[]
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comments $comment): self
    {
        if (!$this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments[] = $comment;
            $comment->setAuteur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeComment(Comments $comment): self
    {
        if ($this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments->removeElement($comment);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($comment->getAuteur() === $this) {
                $comment->setAuteur(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Comments[]
     */
    public function getCommentsOnUser(): Collection
    {
        return $this->commentsOnUser;
    }

    public function addCommentsOnUser(Comments $commentsOnUser): self
    {
        if (!$this->commentsOnUser->contains($commentsOnUser)) {
            $this->commentsOnUser[] = $commentsOnUser;
            $commentsOnUser->setPostedOnUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCommentsOnUser(Comments $commentsOnUser): self
    {
        if ($this->commentsOnUser->contains($commentsOnUser)) {
            $this->commentsOnUser->removeElement($commentsOnUser);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($commentsOnUser->getPostedOnUser() === $this) {
                $commentsOnUser->setPostedOnUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(?string $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that naming an entity "Collection" is not allowed, but it is definitely the source of your problem.

You are requiring `getCollection()` to return a type `Collection` in your code:

```
    /**
     * @return Collection|collections[]
     */
    public function getCollection(): Collection
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }
```

However, you have a use statement at the top of your file:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
```

That is producing the error you are seeing. I would recommend renaming your `Collection` entity to something less confusing, like `CardCollection`. This would be a simple fix to the whole problem.